# Why does the Eq class exist?

Tags: haskell

Suppose I want to define the type `Mod4` of integers modulo 4. After all, Int is `Mod2^64`. One obvious way I could go is

```
data Mod4 = ZeroMod4 | OneMod4 | TwoMod4 | ThreeMod4
```

However I could also do this

```
data Mod4 = Mod4 Integer

instance Eq Mod4 where
  (Mod4 x) == (Mod4 y) = (x-y) `mod` 4 == 0
```

But then this function is problematic :

```
f :: Mod4 -> Mod4
f (Mod4 x) = if x < 20 then Mod4 0 else Mod4 1
```

`f (Mod4 16)` is different from `f (Mod4 20)`, whereas those two arguments are `==`. So I end up with two sorts of equality : representation in memory (
`Mod4 16` is different from `Mod4 20`) and `==`.

Since all functions can pattern match their arguments, they can always bypass any `==` operator. Why didn't Haskell just took the representation in memory as the definition of equality ? This way all types become trivially equatable.

Actually, equality is implied by the very concept of function : a graph that produces equal outputs when given equal inputs. So it makes little sense to speak of a function on a type that is not equatable.

Comment: I don't want `Green` of my `data Color = Red | Green | Blue` to be equal to `True`. At least, implicitly.

Comment: The compiler can tell they're not equal : they don't have the same type.

Comment: "Since all functions can pattern match their arguments" They can't if the argument's type does not export its constructors.

Comment: You broke the abstraction by comparing `x`, not `Mod4 x`, to 20.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to make Mod4 an abstract type.  In the module defining Mod4 you can look at the representation, and make functions like f (but you shouldn't). Outside the defining module you can't cheat, the the equality is the one you want.  This is just an example of how abstract data types work, and why Eq is just the right thing.  It allows you to defining equality for abstract types, that behaves properly.

Comment: Should `f x = True` and `f x = (x < 0) || (x >= 0)` be equal? (given `f :: Integer -> Bool`)

Comment: @immibis : this remark is already covered in chi's answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why didn't Haskell just took the representation in memory as the definition of equality ? This way all types become trivially equatable.

Nope. You can't compare values of type `Integer -> Bool`. Functions can not be compared, in general.

Back to the blackboard. How to design equality in a typed language?

One option is to let `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool`, and throw an exception if `a` is a function. See e.g. Ocaml.

Another option is to partition types in equatable/not equatable. This is `eqtype` in SML.

Another, but related, option is to express "eq-ability" as a constraint on the polymorphism. `Eq` in Haskell.

Now, `Eq` might have been more special. E.g. you can't define its instances by yourself, and you must use `deriving Eq`, similarly to how `Typeable` works now.
The Haskell designers instead to allow users to define their own comparison function. The users might know some "smarter" way. E.g. to compare a 10-field record, start by comparing the usually-different fields, and compare usually-equal ones later, trying to improve efficiency.

Note that, if we don't export the data type constructor, we can make equality to be an equivalence and still be useful. E.g. `Data.Set.Set` equates different (balanced) trees when they represent the same set, yet the exported interface never breaks the equivalence, so equality looks like equality from outside.

> So it makes little sense to speak of a function on a type that is not equatable.

True, when "not equatable" is interpreted in a mathematical sense. However. when it is interpreted as "the equality predicate is not computable", it makes a lot of sense. We can speak of a function working on values whose type has undecidable equality.

Comment: "When the equality predicate is not computable" does this apply to function types like `Int -> Bool` ? Indeed we have functions of functions. Or maybe a more complicated case like [group presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group) ? I believe it is very hard to compute if two group presentations are isomorphic.

Comment: @V.Semeria Yes, given arbitrary `f, g :: Integer -> Bool` we can't decide whether they are the same function. See any computability / recursion theory book/course. Note that e.g. `\x -> 2*x` and `\x -> x+x` are the same function, even if they likely have a different in-memory representation.

Comment: @V.Semeria, the `Data.Set` example chi gives here represents a very common case. *Most* interesting data structures have some amount of "redundancy", allowing more than one concrete representation of the same abstract object. `Data.Set`, `Data.Map`, `Data.Sequence`, the graph types in `fgl`, ropes, heaps, vector slices, B-tree variants of all sorts, functional queues, deques, output-restricted deques, catenable deques, monoidal finger trees, etc., all have non-structural equality.